# Mediation Model with two mediating variables using Lavaan

Tags: mediation, lavaan

I'm trying to set up a mediation model using Lavaan with two mediating variables (as shown in the picture below)

[image]

I'm pretty new to lavaan. Is the following approach to specify and test the model correct?

```
model <- ' # direct effect
Y ~ c*X
# mediator
M ~ a*X
O ~ b*M
Y ~ d*O
# direct effect
direct := c
# indirect effect (a*b*d)
indirect := a*b*d
# total effect
total := c + (a*b*d)

'


fitsem <- sem(model,data=Data,bootstrap = 1000, test = "boot")
summary(fitsem, fit.measures=TRUE, standardize=TRUE, rsquare=TRUE)
```

Comment: This question has been addressed in this [thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/340857/serial-mediation-in-r-how-to-setup-the-model).

Comment: This answer might be helpful. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/340857/serial-mediation-in-r-how-to-setup-the-model