# Serial Mediation in R - how to setup the model?

Tags: r, mediation

The well-known PROCESSr package unfortunately does not support serial mediation in r, as shown by the model below. I have been looking all over the net, but couldn't find a package that would allow me to specify the below model in r.

How would you go about setting up a model like this one in r? Is there a package to do so?

[image: serial mediation]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should probably be migrated to StackOverflow since it is about software, but:

You could do this in the R package `lavaan`. In your model, you would first specify models for `M1`, `M2`, and `Y`. We will want to label all the paths, as well. I will label *c'* as `cp`, for "c-prime":

```
M1 ~ a1 * X
M2 ~ a2 * X + d21 * M1
Y ~  cp * X + b1  * M1 + b2 * M2
```

The indirect effect, `ind_eff` is then defined, per Hayes, as `a1 * d21 * b2`:

```
ind_eff := a1 * d21 * b2
```

You need to put this all in a string object:

```
model <- "
  M1 ~ a1 * X
  M2 ~ a2 * X + d21 * M1
  Y ~  cp * X + b1  * M1 + b2 * M2
  ind_eff := a1 * d21 * b2
"
```

Then you just run the model using bootstrapped confidence intervals to get the confidence interval for the indirect effect (`ind_eff`):

```
fit <- lavaan::sem(model = model, data = dat, se = "boot", bootstrap = 5000)
```

Where `dat` is the name of your data frame and `5000` is the number of bootstrap resamples you would like to do (this will likely take a few minutes).

To look at your results, you can call:

```
lavaan::parameterEstimates(fit, boot.ci.type = "bca.simple")
```

Comment: Thank you Mark. Are there any requirements regarding the variables? In my case variable X is a factor with 3 levels, the other variables are all continous.

Comment: This will assume that your mediators and dependent variable are conditionally normally distributed (per usual). `lavaan`, unless they updated it, requires all variables to be numeric. I would recommend turning the `X` variable into two binary variables (level 1 vs. level 2; level 1 vs. level 3, for example).

Comment: due to my hypothesis, it makes sense to combine level1 and 2 to one level and keep level3 the way it is. Thus the number of cases between the final two levels would be quite different. Is that a problem?

Comment: That works! Just combine two of them into the same level and make it a numeric 0 or 1 variable

Comment: pathcoefficients a2,d21,b1 and b2 all come out significant, yet a1 and cp do not. In particular since there is no significance of a1, it seems that mediation does not take place the way I hypothesized, otherwise, a1 would have also been significant. Would you agree with this Mark?

Comment: Yes, it seems like you have a simple mediation model of X on Y through M2. M1 seems to be related to the phenomenon of interest, as it is correlated with M2 and Y, but since it does not have a relationship with X, you cannot say it serves as a mediator.

Comment: add `ind_eff_2 := a2 * b2` to the code. That will test mediation of X --> M2 --> Y

Comment: @MarkWhite If another mediator was added to the c' path (x -> M3->y),    
  would it be              
: Y ~  (cp1 * X) +(cp2*M3)+( b1  * M1) + (b2 * M2)?

Comment: @MarkWhite How can I compute the total effect? I tried `c := cp + a1*d21*b2` but the result is inaccurate. That is, the `c` is not the same as the one obtained in `Y ~ c*X`. Am I missing something?

Comment: I found the solution [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/476483/serial-mediation-with-3-mediators-lavaan), the total effect is equal to the sum of the partial effect plus *all* indirect effects. Therefore, `c := cp + a1*d21*b2 + a1*b1 + a2*b2`.