# Serial mediation with 3 mediators [lavaan]

Tags: r, model, mediation, lavaan

I want to implement a serial mediation with 3 mediators in R using the package lavaan.

[image: Lavaan Model 6 (3 Mediators)]

I found a code for the serial mediation with 2 mediators in a posting here: [Serial Mediation with 2 mediators](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/340857/serial-mediation-in-r-how-to-setup-the-model)

So basically I tried to extend the model I saw there. From

```
model <- "
  M1 ~ a1 * X
  M2 ~ a2 * X + d21 * M1
  Y ~  cp * X + b1  * M1 + b2 * M2
  ind_eff := a1 * d21 * b2
"
```

to

```
model=
"
  #Regressions
  M1 ~ a*X
  M2 ~ b*M1 + X
  M3 ~ b*M1 + c*M2 + X
  Y ~ d*M3 + c*M2 + M1 + e*X
  
  #Defined Parameters:
  ie := a*b*c*d
  de := e
"
```

Does this model now reflect PROCESS Model 6 with 3 mediators?

Answer (score 1):

Not quite. You would need to specify different paths in lavaan for each arrows in the PROCESS figure. As such, you would need 10 paths, **each with their own unique label**. For example:

```
model <-
'
  #Regressions
  M1 ~ a1*X
  M2 ~ a2*M1 + a3*X
  M3 ~ a4*M1 + a5*M2 + a6*X
  Y  ~ b1*M1 + b2*M2 + b3*M1 + c*X
 '
```

The **total** indirect effect would be the sum of all indirect effects. You could also test individual indirect effects by specifying their unique paths; for example this would be the code for the indirect effect via M1 and via M2, respectively.

```
ieM1 := a1*b1
ieM2 := a1*a2*b2 + a3*b2
```