# Group Comparison with serial mediation

Tags: multiple-comparisons, mediation

I'm trying to compare two groups for a serial mediation model. I wrote my code like in [this link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/340857/serial-mediation-in-r-how-to-setup-the-model)

to make it clearer, here is my code:

```
#singleModel ind4 := b*c; Total_I := b*c + e'

model6 <- 'DV ~ f*IV + e*M1 + c*M2
M1 ~ a*IV
M2 ~ d*IV + b*M1
ind1 := a*b*c
ind2 := a*e
ind3 := d*c
TotalM := a*b*c + a*e + d*c + f'
fitModel6 <- sem(model6, data = buyukdos, estimator = "MLR", missing = "ML")
fitmeasures(fitModel6)
summary(fitModel6, standardized = TRUE, rsquare = TRUE)

#two group model 
Model6gr <- 'DV ~ c(f1,f2)*IV + c(e1,e2)*M1 + c(c1,c2)*M2
M1 ~ c(a1,a2)*IV
M2 ~ c(d1,d2)*IV + c(b1,b2)*M1
#TR_indirect
trind1 := a1*b1*c1
trind2 := a1*e1
trind3 := d1*c1
trTotalM := a1*b1*c1 + a1*e1 + d1*c1 + f1
#FR_indirect
FRind1 := a2*b2*c2
FRind2 := a2*e2
FRind3 := d2*c2
FRTotalM := a2*b2*c2 + a2*e2 + d2*c2 + f2
'
buyukdos$group = as.character(buyukdos$group)
fitModel6gr <- sem(Model6gr, data = buyukdos, estimator = "MLR", missing = "ML", group = "group")
fitmeasures(fitModel6gr)
summary(fitModel6gr, standardized = TRUE, rsquare = TRUE)
#comparison
group_comparison <- lavTestLRT(fitModel6, fitModel6gr)
print(group_comparison)
```

For the group model, I added group specification in the fitting function. **Two models are freely estimated**. I did it to see if there is a difference between with group and without group models. Then, I used `lavTestLRT` to compare chi-squares. However, they got same degrees of freedom and difference was zero as you guess. I checked both models and in both outputs, df looks zero, CFI and TLI look 1.000 and RMSEA as 0.00

What is wrong in my approach?
I really appreciate any kind of help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Greetings! It is impossible to give any good answers without knowing more about how you specified your code (I realize the link includes a model and some code in the answers, but its not clear how you have actually specified the model).

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the mediation model that you estimated in both groups may have been saturated (df = 0). In that case, the chi-square value is zero in both groups and no meaningful comparisons of model fit are possible because the model trivially fits perfectly in both groups. The df and chi-square should be > 0 when you constrain parameters (e.g., path coefficients) to be equal across groups.

Comment: Dear Geiser,
Thanks for your answer. Sorry for my ignorance for this question. I updated the question by adding my model code. However, I guess I did not make any restrictions in a code I wrote in this way. I don't understand how to apply your answer, can you please help me?